# AddFromTemplate() throw exception in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions, envdte, visual-studio-templates

I create Visual Studio C++ project programmatically. I build it by [Solution2.SolAddFromTemplate() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/behck2xd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
//Create VS IDE
Type visualStudioType=Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
DTE dte = (DTE)Activator.CreateInstance(visualStudioType, true);
//Create a solution, based on project template.
Solution2 solution = (Solution2)dte.Solution;
**solution.AddFromTemplate(TemplatePath,DestinationPath, ProjectNane, true);**
```

This code is run successfully, but when I try to create Visual Studio 2012 project, by replace the type of Visual Studio to Visual Studio 2012:

```
Type visualStudioType=Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");
```

instead of:

```
Type visualStudioType=Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
```

It's failed in the mark line (in call to `AddFromTemplate()`), with the exception:

```
Default.js or default.vbs not found in C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects
```

I didn't find any help about this issue. Can anyone help me to solve that?